# How to connect ViewModel with Repository so that data is propagated to the View (MVVM, Livedata)

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I've added some code to make my question more clear.

Retrofit interface:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderAPI {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

    @GET("todos/{number}")
    Call<ResponseBody> getJsonResponse(@Path("number") String number);
}
```

The repository: --> fetchResponse() takes Viewmodel's MutableLiveData as parameter and uses it to update its value and then trigger View to change its UI.

```
public class Repository {

    private final JsonPlaceHolderAPI api;

    public Repository() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        api = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderAPI.class);
    }


    public void fetchResponse(String number, final MutableLiveData<CharSequence> mld){
        final MutableLiveData<CharSequence> ml = new MutableLiveData<>();

        api.getJsonResponse(number).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    mld.setValue(response.body().string());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {}
        });
    }
}
```

The viewModel:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    MutableLiveData<CharSequence> response = new MutableLiveData<>();
    Repository repository;

    public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository();
    }


    public void fetchData(String number) {
        response.setValue("Loading data");
        repository.fetchResponse(number, response);
    }

    public LiveData<? extends CharSequence> getLiveData() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

The View:

```
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        initViews();

        viewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(CharSequence charSequence) {
                if (charSequence != null) {
                    txt.setText(charSequence);
                }
            }
        });


    }
    ...
```

I am not sure if I should pass the MutableLiveData from the viewModel to the Repository.

Is there any recommended way to let viewModel know that data is ready to be published from Repository??

I have read a lot of questions and articles and still I don't get it. I would love if somebody explain to me a nice way to achieve it!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Api

```
public interface TodoApi {
    @GET("todos/")
    Call<List<Todo>> getTodos();

    @GET("todos/{id}")
    Call<Todo> getTodo(@Path("id") long id);
}
```

## Respository

```
    public class TodoRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "TodoRepository";
    private static final TodoRepository ourInstance = new TodoRepository();
    private TodoApi api;

    private MutableLiveData<List<Todo>> todoListLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Todo> todoLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public static TodoRepository getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private TodoRepository() {
        api = ApiBuilder.create(TodoApi.class);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Todo>> getTodos() {
        api.getTodos().enqueue(new Callback<List<Todo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Todo>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Todo>> response) {
                todoListLiveData.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Todo>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: failed to fetch todo list from server");
            }
        });
        return todoListLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<Todo> getTodo(long id) {
        api.getTodo(id).enqueue(new Callback<Todo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Todo> call, @NonNull Response<Todo> response) {
                todoLiveData.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Todo> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: failed to get todo");
            }
        });
        return todoLiveData;
    }
}
```

## ViewModel

```
    public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivityViewModel";

    private TodoRepository repository = TodoRepository.getInstance();

    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLoading = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<List<Todo>> todoLiveData;

    public MainActivityViewModel() {
        super();
        isLoading.setValue(true);
        todoLiveData = repository.getTodos();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getIsLoading() {
        return isLoading;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Todo>> getTodoLiveData() {
        return todoLiveData;
    }
}
```

## View

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    todoListRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.todo_recycler_view);
    loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.todo_loading_indicator);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Todos");

    mViewModel.getIsLoading().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Boolean isLoading) {
            if (isLoading) loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    mViewModel.getTodoLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Todo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Todo> todos) {
            mViewModel.getIsLoading().postValue(false);
            initRecyclerView(todos);
        }
    });
}
```

## For full sample

https://github.com/AnvarNazar/RetrofitTypicodeApiExample

Comment: I appreciate that you shared this with me. But, in this one the repository does not return the data. In contrast, it returns the Call and the the viewmodel makes the http request. This would work well but I think it violates separation of.concerns since viewmodel makes the http request

Comment: Yes you are right. But it can be easily altered to do network call from repository then return the livedata and observe from viewmodel and view. I have updated my answer

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean and it works.
I thought for some reason that it's viewModel's responsibility to update the Livedata. But in your example the it is updated straight from repository

Comment: Why did you prefer to user postValue() instead of setValue()?
It's not running in the background thread

Comment: Call.enqueue method is an asynchronous task and runs the request on the background thread. Is that right. I am not exactly sure

Comment: Although enqueue runs in the background thread, the onResponse callback runs in the main UI. I've checked that with making some logs and look the running thread!

Comment: But how would you call the getTodo(long id) method from ViewModel and in turn how would you pass the id from the Activity torm Activity to ViewModel.

Comment: Repository returns data before network call finishes. How to handle that?

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa. Repository will return the live data object before the network call finishes. It is the expected behavior. You can observe the live data object from your viewmodel for changes. The repository will update the data in the live data object after the network call finishes and the view will get notified about the changes in that live data object if you are observing it. Please look into Live Data and understand how it works.

Comment: when the screen is rotated, it calls the network API again. How to handle this?

Comment: Another way of connecting Activity and Retrofit MVVM can be found in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65908848/4300670

Comment: How would this work in case of Error response ?? Since there is no way of telling ViewModel from Repository that there was some network error or error response from server to handle accordingly.

Comment: @SharpEdge you can check out NetworkBoundResource class, the very last section in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

Comment: Also the viewModel initialized the repository as a property, when you unit testing you are unable to swap in a mock repository