# How to link Retrofit and Repository/ViewModel for a MVVM pattern?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit2, android-architecture-components

I have trouble linking Retrofit with MVVM architecture. Indeed, after reading documentation where they only talk about Room which is for SQLite local database, I searched the same but for data that comes from a Rest Server.
So, I tried to do something similar to this and it doesn't worked :
https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1

I have an Activity that observes a ViewModel :

Activity code :

```
mFlightPlanViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FlightPlanViewModel.class);
        mFlightPlanViewModel.getFlightPlans().observe(this, (flightPlans) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_CHANGED");

            mFlightPlanAdapter.setFlightPlans(flightPlans);
        });
```

The ViewModel :

```
public class FlightPlanViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "FlightPlanViewModel";

    private LiveData<List<FlightPlan>> mFlightPlans;
    private FlightPlanRepository mFlightPlanRepository;

    public FlightPlanViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        Log.d(TAG, "CONSTRUCTOR");

        mFlightPlanRepository = FlightPlanRepository.getInstance();
        mFlightPlans = mFlightPlanRepository.getFlightPlans();
    }

    public LiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
        Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

        return mFlightPlans;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel answers the Repository which uses a singleton pattern :

```
public class FlightPlanRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "FlightPlanRepository";

    private static FlightPlanRepository instance;
    private RestApi mRestApi;

    private FlightPlanRepository() {
        Log.d(TAG, "CONSTRUCTOR");

        mRestApi = RestDao.getRestDao();
    }

    public static FlightPlanRepository getInstance() {
        Log.d(TAG, "GET_INSTANCE");

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FlightPlanRepository();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
        Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

        final MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        mRestApi.getFlightPlanList().enqueue(new Callback<List<FlightPlan>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Response<List<FlightPlan>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    List<FlightPlan> temp = response.body();
                    for (FlightPlan flightPlan : temp) {
                        Log.d(TAG + "res", flightPlan.toString());
                    }
                    data.setValue(response.body());
                    Log.d(TAG + "res", response.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Throwable t) {
                List<FlightPlan> flightPlans = new ArrayList<>();
                flightPlans.add(new FlightPlan(0, "Test", 3.551, 50.52, 3.55122, 50.52625));
                data.setValue(flightPlans);
                Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

The repository uses a Retrofit instance :

```
public class RestDao {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.78:8080";
    private static Retrofit instance;

    private static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RestApi getRestDao() {
        return getInstance().create(RestApi.class);
    }
}
```

It uses this interface :

```
public interface RestApi {
    @GET("/plan/list")
    Call<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlanList();
}
```

The part of the code that doesn't work is :

```
public MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
    Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

    final MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    mRestApi.getFlightPlanList().enqueue(new Callback<List<FlightPlan>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Response<List<FlightPlan>> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                List<FlightPlan> temp = response.body();
                for (FlightPlan flightPlan : temp) {
                    Log.d(TAG + "res", flightPlan.toString());
                }
                data.setValue(response.body());
                Log.d(TAG + "res", response.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Throwable t) {
            List<FlightPlan> flightPlans = new ArrayList<>();
            flightPlans.add(new FlightPlan(0, "Test", 3.551, 50.52, 3.55122, 50.52625));
            data.setValue(flightPlans);
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

This return a null list. I think that I understand why : calling enqueue() method made a request that is in an other Thread so here we return data without waiting for the result.

So my question is how to link Retrofit and my ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what happens when there is a response if I do that ?

```
public LiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
    Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

    MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    mRestApi.getFlightPlanList().enqueue(new Callback<List<FlightPlan>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Response<List<FlightPlan>> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                data.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Throwable t) {
            // Do something
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

I you run that, there is fistly a null object returned but if there is a response, will it return something ?

I tried that :

```
public LiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
    Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

    MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    List<FlightPlan> flightPlans;

    try {
        Response<List<FlightPlan>> response = mRestApi.getFlightPlanList().execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            flightPlans = response.body();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't get data !");
            throw new Exception("Can't get data !");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        flightPlans = new ArrayList<>();
        flightPlans.add(new FlightPlan(5, "Test5", 3.551, 50.52, 3.55122, 50.52625));
    }

    data.setValue(flightPlans);
    Log.d(TAG, data.getValue().toString());

    return data;
}
```

Now it crashes on the execute line because I launch that in the main thread..
So I have to made an async task but where ?

Other option : Make an async task like at first, put a setter to the model view object and when there is a response I call the setter.. Is that good to do ?

Thanks for the aswers you gave me ! It was very helpful.

EDIT : Why is there this code on Google Documentation :

```
public class UserRepository {
    private Webservice webservice;
    // ...
    public LiveData<User> getUser(int userId) {
        // This isn't an optimal implementation. We'll fix it later.
        final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        webservice.getUser(userId).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                data.setValue(response.body());
            }

            // Error case is left out for brevity.
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

It means that it's ok to do such thing ?

SOLUTION !

EDIT :

[How to connect ViewModel with Repository so that data is propagated to the View (MVVM, Livedata)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883817/how-to-connect-viewmodel-with-repository-so-that-data-is-propagated-to-the-view)

This helps me a lot !!!

I found the solution ! I'm stupid : I insert old dependencies in the gradle file !

Answer (score 1):

Hey Kevin just a minor change to your code.Instead of MutableLiveData return LiveData from your repository :

```
public LiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
    Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

    final MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    mRestApi.getFlightPlanList().enqueue(new Callback<List<FlightPlan>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Response<List<FlightPlan>> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                List<FlightPlan> temp = response.body();
                for (FlightPlan flightPlan : temp) {
                    Log.d(TAG + "res", flightPlan.toString());
                }
                data.postValue(response.body());
                Log.d(TAG + "res", response.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Throwable t) {
            List<FlightPlan> flightPlans = new ArrayList<>();
            flightPlans.add(new FlightPlan(0, "Test", 3.551, 50.52, 3.55122, 50.52625));
            data.postValue(flightPlans);
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick answer. I tried what you told me but it still returning a null list. That's weird..

Comment: Are you getting response in your api?

Comment: When I start my app, it crashes because I give the response to a recycler view adapter.. But if I add a default entry in my code it displays only the default value.

Comment: Could you post your activity code also. Also check whether your api is returning you the correct list of data

Answer (score 0):

If I do that :

```
public LiveData<List<FlightPlan>> getFlightPlans() {
    Log.d(TAG, "GET_FLIGHT_PLANS");

    final MutableLiveData<List<FlightPlan>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();


    List<FlightPlan> flightPlans = new ArrayList<>();
    flightPlans.add(new FlightPlan(5, "Test5", 3.551, 50.52, 3.55122, 50.52625));
    data.setValue(flightPlans);
    Log.d(TAG, data.getValue().toString());


    mRestApi.getFlightPlanList().enqueue(new Callback<List<FlightPlan>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Response<List<FlightPlan>> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                List<FlightPlan> temp = response.body();
                for (FlightPlan flightPlan : temp) {
                    Log.d(TAG + "res", flightPlan.toString());
                }
                data.setValue(response.body());
                Log.d(TAG + "res", response.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FlightPlan>> call, Throwable t) {
            List<FlightPlan> flightPlans = new ArrayList<>();
            flightPlans.add(new FlightPlan(0, "Test", 3.551, 50.52, 3.55122, 50.52625));
            data.setValue(flightPlans);
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

I can see in the Logcat the default value, and two value which comes from my rest server but strings are null values and int / doubles are at 0 and it doesn't add the two rest entries to the recycler view.

Here is my activity code :

```
public class FlightPlanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, LifecycleOwner {
    private static final String TAG = "FlightPlanActivity";

    private FlightPlanAdapter mFlightPlanAdapter;
    private FlightPlanViewModel mFlightPlanViewModel;

    /**
     * UI
     */
    private FloatingActionButton mAddPlanButton;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight_plan);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        this.setTitle("Flight Plans");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.flight_plan_list);
        mAddPlanButton = findViewById(R.id.add_flight_plan);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refresh_flight_plan_list);

        mAddPlanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        mFlightPlanAdapter = new FlightPlanAdapter();

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFlightPlanAdapter);

        mFlightPlanViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FlightPlanViewModel.class);
        mFlightPlanViewModel.getFlightPlans().observe(this, (flightPlans) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_CHANGED");

            mFlightPlanAdapter.setFlightPlans(flightPlans);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == mAddPlanButton.getId()) {
            // TODO: A implémenter
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mFlightPlanAdapter.setFlightPlans(mFlightPlanViewModel.getFlightPlans().getValue());

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you  only get your default value in recyclerview. Your rest api values are coming as null and 0. Is that it?

Comment: Check in your activities observer whether the size of the list it's getting is equal to the size of  your api resonse

Comment: I get this in logcat :2019-04-27 23:18:41.579 26214-26214/fr.kevin.myapplication D/FlightPlanRepository: [FlightPlan{mId=5, mName='Test5', mLat1=3.551, mLon1=50.52, mLat2=3.55122, mLon2=50.52625}]
2019-04-27 23:18:41.799 26214-26214/fr.kevin.myapplication D/FlightPlanRepositoryres: FlightPlan{mId=0, mName='null', mLat1=0.0, mLon1=0.0, mLat2=0.0, mLon2=0.0}
2019-04-27 23:18:41.799 26214-26214/fr.kevin.myapplication D/FlightPlanRepositoryres: FlightPlan{mId=0, mName='null', mLat1=0.0, mLon1=0.0, mLat2=0.0, mLon2=0.0}                                 and the size is 1.

Comment: I found this following video https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=retrofit+viewmodel where there is an implementation to consume a rest server through mvvm pattern. It gets the data in the view and stores it by using insert() method of the ViewModel. He links the viewModel to a sqlite database for caching. It seems that if i want to get my rest data, i have to do it like this..

Comment: Its not necessary to do that. You can directly populate your view with your rest data. I didn't think you have any thing wrong in your code too.

Comment: We can do asynchronous and synchronous tasks with retrofit. Here i do an asynchronous task so the method doesn't wait for the result and return a null value. I can try a synchronous request but i that case, I have to make the call in the activity with an async task i think.