# Why retrofit returning Null 'LiveData' even after setting return value non-null correctly?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I got the response correctly, set value of LiveData correctly (got confirmed by printing value on console after setting value to live data). But When i tried to print same thing just before "return" it's giving me NullPointerException.

```
public class ProjectRepository {

private ProjectRepository instance;
Context context;
public ProjectRepository(Context context) {
  this.context=context;
}
private MutableLiveData<List<PojoDivision>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
public LiveData<List<PojoDivision>> getDivisionList() {
    ((RetrofitConfiguration)context).getDivisionRestApiWithAuthentication().getDivisionList().enqueue(new Callback<List<PojoDivision>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PojoDivision>> call, Response<List<PojoDivision>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(response.body().get(4).getName()); // this is printing

                data.setValue(response.body());
                System.out.println(data.getValue().get(4).getName()); // this is printing
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<PojoDivision>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
    /*
    following code is not printing with nullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
     */
    System.out.println(data.getValue().get(4).getName());
    return data;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is that you are calling the problematic line right after you enqueue your request. The response haven't arrived yet but you want to print it. It works in your `onResponse` because it is called when the response has arrived (as the name shows). To get an understanding on callbacks you may read this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/java-basics-for-retrofit-callbacks

Comment: @agiro so this way i am returning null from method? So how to return correct value that i got in my response?

Comment: Your request hasn't returned with anything when you are printing that value, that's why it is null. You have something to print when your request has received a response - and you get notified using the callback you implemented. In other words if you want to operate on your response reliably, you need to use the `onResponse` method.

Comment: @agiro then how to return correct value to caller of this method?, i am stuck. If you could help me out?

Comment: The easiest I can think of is passing a `Consumer<Response<List<PojoDivision>>>` as method parameter to `getDivisionList()` and invoking it from `onResponse`. EDIT by the way what is your minimum API level? you can use consumer after API level 24.

Comment: you can see here the similar example, in accepted answer they are returning value in same way, your comment?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883817/how-to-connect-viewmodel-with-repository-so-that-data-is-propagated-to-the-view

Comment: You can of course return the `LiveData` which will notify its observers when you actually have a response. The issue with your code is that you immediately access it after making the call.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a LiveData object at the class level for your repository class, your method has no need to return anything.  Instead it's responsibility is for updating that LiveData object.

```
public class ProjectRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "ProjectRepository";

    private ProjectRepository instance;
    Context context;

    public ProjectRepository(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<PojoDivision>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void getDivisionList() {
        ((RetrofitConfiguration) context).getDivisionRestApiWithAuthentication().getDivisionList().enqueue(new Callback<List<PojoDivision>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<PojoDivision>> call, Response<List<PojoDivision>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    data.postValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<PojoDivision>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The clients of this class would need to 1) observe the LiveData object, and 2) call the `getDivisionList()` method to trigger an update:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProjectRepository repository;

    private void setRepository() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) return;
        repository = new ProjectRepository(context);
    }

    public void observeData() {
        repository.data.observe(this, new Observer<List<PojoDivision>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<PojoDivision> pojoDivisions) {
                // do something with updated data
            }
        });
    }

    public void triggerUpdate() {
        repository.getDivisionList();
    }
}
```

Comment: but i don't want repository data to be observed from fragment, I want this from Viewmodel.

Comment: LiveData isn't meant to be observed from a ViewModel - the observer is typically responsible for taking the data and applying it to the view.  You may want to consider holding the LiveData object in your ViewModel, and having the repository simply return (via a callback) the data to the ViewModel to massage and post to its LiveData object.